# jQuery, Dequeue an ajaxQueue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the ajaxQueue mentioned in the example [Queueing something like Ajax Calls](http://learn.jquery.com/effects/uses-of-queue-and-dequeue/):

```
// jQuery on an empty object, we are going to use this as our queue
var ajaxQueue = $({});
$.ajaxQueue = function( ajaxOpts ) {
    // Hold the original complete function.
    var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;
    // Queue our ajax request.
    ajaxQueue.queue(function( next ) {
        // Create a complete callback to fire the next event in the queue.
        ajaxOpts.complete = function() {
            // Fire the original complete if it was there.
            if ( oldComplete ) {
                oldComplete.apply( this, arguments );
            }
            // Run the next query in the queue.
            next();
        };
        // Run the query.
        $.ajax( ajaxOpts );
    });
};
```

I also have a function to make the Ajax Call and append the result to a div (simplified):

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajaxQueue({
        type: "POST",
        url: myURL,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function( result ) {
            $('#divID').append($('<div/>').html($(result).html()).fadeIn(200));
        }
    });
}
```

Then on a click event I loop through the ajax call (simplified):

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    // ( ??? ) Dequeue the ajaxQueue
    $('#divID').html(''); // Clear current results
    for(var i=0; i<15; i++) {
        ajaxCall();
    }
});
```

**The Problem**
If a user clicks on the link while the queue is still running, a new queue of ajax calls is added up, resulting to more results than expected. I need to clear the queue on click, before a new loop starts.

Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4AQ9N/1/).
Any recommendations very much appreciated.

Comment: So when user clicks on link 2nd time, what should happen to results already retrieved by first click?

Comment: @rahulmaindargi I just want the results to be cleared (removed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [clearQueue](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/):

```
ajaxQueue.clearQueue();
```

**EDIT**

The problem is there might still be an ajax request being called.

So you might want to keep track of the current request:

```
currentRequest = $.ajax( ajaxOpts );
```

And abort this one when clearing the queue:

```
if (currentRequest) {
    currentRequest.abort();
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4AQ9N/6/

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried that, but still some previous results are left over. On the jsFiddle example I have provided, if you add this code and then click the link three times fast, the results go up to 42, instead of 40. Can you try it and let me know?

Comment: Thank you very very much! That indeed worked! I think jQuery Docs should mention this...

Comment: It's just a small code example in the jQuery Docs. This example also doesn't return the promise, so you can't do something like `$.ajaxQueue({...}).done(function(response) { ... });`. If you want a more complete implementation, have a look at https://gist.github.com/gnarf37/1039247

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
   ajaxQueue.queue("fx", []); // fx is defualt queue Name.
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4AQ9N/7/)**

```
 success: function( result ) {
            if(num!=0){
                $('#divID').append($('<div/>').html('Result '+num).fadeIn(300));
            }
            num++;
        }

$("#btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(ajaxQueue.queue().length>0){
        num = 0;
        ajaxQueue.queue("fx", []);
    }else{
        num = 1;
    }
    $('#divID').html(''); // Clear current results



    for(var i=0; i<40; i++) {
        ajaxCall();
    }

});
```

Here you might see 1 extra output...i.e. upto 41. but its not becuase of queue not working... when you `Clear the queue` there is one ajax call already placed... and waiting for response.
the response is recieved after the queue is complete.

I have added the updated the code with some num value hack. it will work most of the times.

Comment: Thank you... I have the same results with using `ajaxQueue.clearQueue();`. If you click the link 3 times fast, the results go up to 42. (Each additional click leaves behind one previous result). Do you think there's something wrong on clearing the previous content with `$('#divID').html('');`?

Comment: Hmmm... The `num` is just a dummy value to demonstrate my problem. Results will actually be real content. sroes solution worked fine. Thank you again...